# grand-canonical ensemble

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-statistics

I was wondering if the following reasoning is correct for example for electrons in the classical or qm grand-canonical ensemble?

Is it always valid in the grandcanonical ensemble to calculate the energy and chemical potential from this:
For the Landau-potential we have
$$\phi = -pV.$$

Thus the energy for non-ultrarelativistic particles(for these we'd have $E = \frac{1}{3}pV$) is $$E = \frac{2}{3}pV = -\frac{2}{3}\phi.$$

Now the chemical potential is given by

$$\mu = \frac{G}{N} = \frac{E + pV - TS}{N} $$

Now we could say $N = \langle N \rangle$,$E = -\frac{2}{3}\phi$ and also $-TS = T \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial T}$.

This would give us

$$\mu = \frac{G}{N} = \frac{-\frac{5}{3} \phi + T \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial T}}{\langle N \rangle} .$$

Is this a valid expression in the grand-canonical ensemble for let's say electrons?